# Bumper in the gmapping costmap (Turtlebot)

Tags: navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use the bumper scans to avoid small obstacles with gmapping, I added this bump scan in the costmap_common_params.yaml file in the turtlebot_navigation package.
Below is what is happening :

- When the robot bumps in an obstacle, the obstacle is put in the costmap
- When the robot go backward, the bumper is not pressed anymore and the laser sensor is not seeing the obstacle so the obstacle is instantaneously removed from the costmap.
  I would like the obstacle to stay longer in the costmap so that the navigation stack would change the path to avoid it.
  Is it possible to modify this in the costmap ?

Thanks,
Caroline

UPDATE : yaml file

```
max_obstacle_height: 0.60 
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.18
inflation_radius: 0.50
observation_sources: 
   scan
   bump

scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
bump: {data_type: PointCloud2, topic: mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud, marking: true, clearing: false}
```

Where would you add the min_height parameter ? I tried with "scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height:0.30}" but the costmap is not existing anymore in rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58111/bumper-in-the-gmapping-costmap-(turtlebot)/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Cheap fix is to set the "clearing" parameter for your laser to false, but probably you still want the laser to do both marking and clearing.

So I would try to play with "min_obstacle_height" and "max_obstacle_height" parameters for both laser and bumper scan; I didn't try this, but I suppose that if bumper obstacles are below laser ones and do not overlap, laser will not clear bumper hits. Can you post your YAML file?

Btw, if you are using Turtlebot 2, there'is a package to publish bumper events as a PointCloud so it can be fussed in a costmap: [kobuki_bumper2pc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kobuki_bumper2pc)

Hope this helps.

Yes, you can use different values for different sensors. Try this (I didn't!):

```
max_obstacle_height: 0.60 
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.18
inflation_radius: 0.50
observation_sources: 
   scan
   bump

scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0.25, max_obstacle_height: 0.35}
bump: {data_type: PointCloud2, topic: mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud, marking: true, clearing: false, min_obstacle_height: 0.01, max_obstacle_height: 0.10}
```

I set typical values for Turtlebot 2.

**Update:**

This works for me... surprisingly! I have read the wiki for costmap2d and min/max obstacle_height are just intended to filter out sensor data above the robot or low enough to be ignored. In fact, afaik, costmap2d keeps no track of which sensor marked/cleared an obstacle, nor at which height it was spotted; if so, my previous reasoning is simply stupid. So I suppose this because of another reason.

Maybe what you need is to use a voxel map, who contains 3D information. I didn't use them by now (set map_type as "voxel")

**New update:**

I have being experimenting with voxel maps to fuse information from three different sensors and it works fine. But you must be careful when setting  min/max obstacle_height for any sensor so each one fits in its voxel, and so they don't interfere with each other. The default voxel map's z_resolution is 0.2, what means that every sensor must be separated by at least 20 cm. Here are my voxel maps and sensors configuration:

```
...
origin_z: 0.0
z_resolution: 0.1
z_voxels: 3
...

...
kn_scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0.2, max_obstacle_height: 0.3}
ir_scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: ir_scan, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: 0.1, max_obstacle_height: 0.2}
bumpers: {data_type: PointCloud2, topic: mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud, marking: true, clearing: false, min_obstacle_height: 0.0, max_obstacle_height: 0.1}
```

This works as expected but, as I don't know the internals of costmap, I'm not sure whether my conclusions are right or I just have been lucky!

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-03-15**:
Thanks for help.
Yes as you said I would like the laser to do both marking and clearing.
I tried to add the min_obstacle_height and maximum_obstacle_height but I am not sure I can use different parameters for laser and bumpers... I added my yaml file in an update.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-03-29**:
Sorry for the huge lapse for responding; I hope you fix your problem. Check my update if not.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-04-01**:
Hey, thanks for your update. I tried to do exactly the same thing than you but when I do that, I can not see the costmap anymore in rviz, the obstacles and inflated obstacles are not in rviz anymore...

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-04-03**:
mmm....  there'is a missing comma in my configuration; I have fixed it. Apart from this, I have being playing a bit with costmap2d. I have updated my answer accordingly.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-04-08**:
Hello, it doesn't seem to work with my robot. When I add the minimum height and maximum height (as you did) I can't see the costmap anymore for the laser. The costmap has only the points provided by the bumper...

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-04-08**:
Note that if the laser scan height is not within the min and max values it will be filtered out. The values I put match for the TurtleBot2 Kinect position

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-03**:
I updated my answer again. I think now I understand what was happening

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-03**:
Hi jorge,
thanks for the update. I finally decided to use the bumpers only for safety controller, so the obstacles are not really stored in the costmap. I didn't test it but what you said about the voxel map seems to be a good solution.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-03**:
I  am also thinking about using the Kinect data instead of the bumpers data to detect obstacles my Hokuyo laser cannot see.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-14**:
Hi jorge, I just updated my algorithm to take into account the Kinect data to see obstacles that are above the laser range finder. I used a voxel map as you suggested and it works well. So I think voxel maps are a very good way for these kind of things.